# How to create table of time distribution by tags in Org Mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock, org-clock-table

My `.org`-file contains tasks tagged as: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g`.  I want to create table of time distribution by tags `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.

```
    | Tag | Time Spent |  % |
    |-----+------------+----|
    | a   |      00:30 | 25 |
    | b   |      00:30 | 25 |
    | c   |      00:30 | 25 |
    | d   |      00:30 | 25 |
```

What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this Gist: https://gist.github.com/tsu-nera/d9ffa6a51a6e7bdb957b

Add it to `init.el`:

```
(require 'org-table)
(require 'org-clock)

(defun clocktable-by-tag/shift-cell (n)
  (let ((str ""))
    (dotimes (i n)
      (setq str (concat str "| ")))
    str))

(defun clocktable-by-tag/insert-tag (params)
  (let ((tag (plist-get params :tags)))
    (insert "|--\n")
    (insert (format "| %s | *Tag time* |\n" tag))
    (let ((total 0))
  (mapcar
       (lambda (file)
     (let ((clock-data (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
                 (org-clock-get-table-data (buffer-name) params))))
       (when (> (nth 1 clock-data) 0)
         (setq total (+ total (nth 1 clock-data)))
         (insert (format "| | File *%s* | %.2f |\n"
                 (file-name-nondirectory file)
                 (/ (nth 1 clock-data) 60.0)))
         (dolist (entry (nth 2 clock-data))
           (insert (format "| | . %s%s | %s %.2f |\n"
                   (org-clocktable-indent-string (nth 0 entry))
                   (nth 1 entry)
                   (clocktable-by-tag/shift-cell (nth 0 entry))
                   (/ (nth 3 entry) 60.0)))))))
       (org-agenda-files))
      (save-excursion
    (re-search-backward "*Tag time*")
    (org-table-next-field)
    (org-table-blank-field)
    (insert (format "*%.2f*" (/ total 60.0)))))
    (org-table-align)))

(defun org-dblock-write:clocktable-by-tag (params)
  (insert "| Tag | Headline | Time (h) |\n")
  (insert "|     |          | <r>  |\n")
  (let ((tags (plist-get params :tags)))
    (mapcar (lambda (tag)
          (setq params (plist-put params :tags tag))
          (clocktable-by-tag/insert-tag params))
        tags)))

(provide 'clocktable-by-tag)
```

And use it in your `.org`-file:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable-by-tag :tags ("a" "b" "c" "d") :maxlevel 2
#+END:
```

Comment: This used to work for me using org-mode 9.1.14 but it's stopped working with org-mode 9.2.1. I have a stack trace I could share but it's pretty big.

Comment: The parameters for `org-clock-get-table-data` have changed. `:tags` is now just a flag that means include the headline's tags when non-nil. However, you can now filter by tags using `:match`.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/ironchicken/6b5424bc2024b3d0a58a8a130f73c2ee