# Sum clock times by tag

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I would like to sum clock intervals from tasks by tag. I found [this blog post](https://sachachua.com/blog/2008/01/tagging-in-org-plus-bonus-code-for-timeclocks-and-tags/) (code below). When I use it, I get the same report, regardless of the tag I request:

```
Time: 4499:28 (4499 hours and 28 minutes)
```

Furthermore, I get this warning after evaluating the code:

```
‘org-re’ is an obsolete macro (as of Org 9.0); you can safely remove it.
```

The post is from 2008 and therefore I assume that the code is incompatible with my version.

How can I sum clocked intervals for a specific tag?

**Appendix**: here is the obsolete code:

```lisp
(defun wicked/org-calculate-tag-time (matcher &optional ts te)
  "Return the total minutes clocked in headlines matching MATCHER.
MATCHER is a string or a Lisp form to be evaluated, testing if a
given set of tags qualifies a headline for inclusion. TS and TE
are time start (inclusive) and time end (exclusive). Call with a
prefix to be prompted for TS and TE.

For example, to see how much time you spent on tasks tagged as
URGENT, call M-x wicked/org-calculate-tag-time RET URGENT RET. To
see how much time you spent on tasks tagged as URGENT today, call
C-u M-x wicked/org-calculate-tag-time RET URGENT RET . RET +1 RET."
  (interactive (list
        (read-string "Tag query: ")
        (if current-prefix-arg (org-read-date))
        (if current-prefix-arg (org-read-date))))
  ;; Convert strings to proper arguments
  (if (stringp matcher) (setq matcher (cdr (org-make-tags-matcher matcher))))
  (if (stringp ts)
      (setq ts (time-to-seconds (apply 'encode-time (org-parse-time-string ts)))))
  (if (stringp te)
      (setq te (time-to-seconds (apply 'encode-time (org-parse-time-string te)))))
  (let* ((re (concat "[\n\r]" outline-regexp " *\\(\\<\\("
             (mapconcat 'regexp-quote org-todo-keywords-1 "\\|")
             (org-re
              "\\>\\)\\)? *\\(.*?\\)\\(:[[:alnum:][email protected]:]+:\\)?[ \t]*$")))
     (case-fold-search nil)
         lspos
     tags tags-list tags-alist (llast 0) rtn level category i txt p
     marker entry priority (total 0))
    (save-excursion
      (org-clock-sum ts te)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward re nil t)
    (catch :skip
      (setq tags (if (match-end 4) (match-string 4)))
      (goto-char (setq lspos (1+ (match-beginning 0))))
      (setq level (org-reduced-level (funcall outline-level))
        category (org-get-category))
      (setq i llast llast level)
      ;; remove tag lists from same and sublevels
      (while (>= i level)
        (when (setq entry (assoc i tags-alist))
          (setq tags-alist (delete entry tags-alist)))
        (setq i (1- i)))
      ;; add the nex tags
      (when tags
        (setq tags (mapcar 'downcase (org-split-string tags ":"))
          tags-alist
          (cons (cons level tags) tags-alist)))
      ;; compile tags for current headline
      (setq tags-list
        (if org-use-tag-inheritance
            (apply 'append (mapcar 'cdr tags-alist))
          tags))
      (when (and (eval matcher)
             (or (not org-agenda-skip-archived-trees)
             (not (member org-archive-tag tags-list))))
        ;; Get the time for the headline at point
        (goto-char (line-beginning-position))
        (setq total (+ total (or (get-text-property (1+ (point)) :org-clock-minutes) 0)))
        ;; if we are to skip sublevels, jump to end of subtree
        (org-end-of-subtree t)))))
    (if (interactive-p)
    (let* ((h (/ total 60))
           (m (- total (* 60 h))))
      (message "Time: %d:%02d (%d hours and %d minutes)" h m h m)))
    total))
```

Comment: There are a couple of questions already answered about clocking tables and tags, 
like [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32178/how-to-create-table-of-time-distribution-by-tags-in-org-mode) or more probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545767/org-mode-clock-table-by-tag). I do understand that you're after a different use case, but further clarification will help.

Comment: I agree with @Muihlinn: instead of showing what code does *not* work, you should show an example org file and what you expect to get.

Comment: The solution with the clock report in the second link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545767/org-mode-clock-table-by-tag) worked for me (`#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope file :tags "nicetag"`). I can't mark it as a duplicate: would you like to write an answer? Thanks for the comment @NickD: next time I'll ask what I want to do first, and add an example of a way that failed after.

Comment: Yes, the "duplicate" is on SO. You can always write your own answer and accept it though (and a "link-only" answer might be acceptable in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545767/org-mode-clock-table-by-tag) @Muihlinn's comment, one solution consists of a clock report:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope file :tags "nicetag"
...
#+END:
```

I can't mark this question as a duplicate since the other solution is on a different forum.